# Default CultureInfo.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator for Poland is "space"?

Tags: localization, internationalization, number-formatting

Our Polish users didn't seem to use that convention as far as I can see on some materials I have.  I was under the impression that most of our continental European users (da-dk, pl-pl, nl-nl) would be formatting N.NNN.NNN,NN and our British Isles users (en-gb, en-ie) would be formatting N,NNN,NNN.NN.

But the reports in our tests for the Polish users started coming out with spaces, and it looked odd to me, and this seems to be due to a space in CultureInfo.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator, and I don't think we put it there.

Any Poles out there want to comment on this convention?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is space. Not just in Polish, but for example in French (IIRC).
And of course, in this case it is thousands separator.

Definitely, when I am about to write a thousand two hundred thirty four point (sic!) fifty six it would look like:

> 1 234,56

And yes, this is valid representation of Polish number format. Although 1234,56 is as good. The real challenge could be reading large numbers, like hundred thousands.